# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

How to fix this error?

Here is it:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata

And here is my pom.xml file

```xml
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.4</version>
   <relativePath/>
</parent>
<groupId>io.x</groupId>
<artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>eureka-server</name>
<description>Eureka server</description>
<properties>
   <java.version>16</java.version></docker.artifact.version>
   <spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server.version>1.4.7.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
       <version>${spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server.version}</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
           <version>Hoxton.SR12</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I think you have incompatible dependencies, spring-boot ver `2.5.4` and `spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server` version `1.4.7.RELEASE`

Comment: @pleft    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> - same error

Comment: Hoxton isn't compatible with boot 2.5 afaik only unto 2.3. Use the 2020.0.3 version instead for 2.4 and higher compatibility.

Comment: you can find the compatible version from here:https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud @Artthur

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using *Spring Boot* `2.5.4` with *Spring Cloud* `Hoxton.SR12`.

As stated in the Spring Cloud compatibility matrix [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud), *Spring Cloud* `Hoxton.SR12` is compatible with *Spring Boot* `2.2.x`, `2.3.x`. So you have to choose the right combination.

If you want to simplify the version choosing, you can use the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try (or adapt yours as) the following `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spring version in pom.xml:

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

   <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
   </properties>

     <dependencies>   

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
     </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```