# Api-gateway(Microservice - Springoot project ) - unable to run service . I want to register this service as client with eureka

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

[image][image]

Error in the attached docs.

I added netflix eureka dependency in pom.xml and in yml file.

**This is yml file.**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: GATEWAY-SERVICE
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: order-service
          uri: lb://ORDER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/order/**
        - id: payment-service
          uri: lb://PAYMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/payment/**

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost

server:
  port: 8989
```

**This is pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-service</name>
    <description>api-service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR12</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope my configuration will help you. This is how the YML file on the client side looks like:

```
###############################################################
# SERVER CONFIG
###############################################################
server:
  port: 8083

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway

###############################################################
# EUREKA CONFIG
###############################################################
eureka:
  client:
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 1
    eureka-connection-idle-timeout-seconds: 30000
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://load-balancer:8070/eureka/
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 1

ribbon:
  ServerListRefreshInterval: 1000
```

Also, don't forget to add the **@EnableEurekaClient** annotation above the main class of the microservice:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class GatewayApplication {
...
}
```

I added the dependency to Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    ...
}
```

And this is an example of the Eureka server microservice:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: load-balancer

server:
  port: 8070

  tomcat:
    max-threads: 100000

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true
  ReadTimeout: 60000
  connection-timeout: 30000
  NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
  NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.WeightResponseTimeRule

eureka:
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: false
    response-cache-update-interval-ms: 1000
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

Don't forget to add the **@EnableEurekaServer** annotation above the main class of the Eureka server application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class LoadBalancerApplication {
...
}
```

Finally, I added the dependency to Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server'
    ...
}
```

Comment: i copied your yml code. but still the same error. screen Shot added. i have not added gradle dependency. i am using maven.

Comment: can you add the right side of the error? do you have annotations in Application classes?

Comment: You can find logs and screenshot here. 
https://duccdu-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/20036762064_physics_edu_du_ac_in/EnYDnyVUBfNCiEFmulnku2kBQuGj9hUe9ND5UtGSJ4vpfw?e=WlGbf2

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030808/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-boot-context-pr